Smooth Interia Scrolling in Nextjs
I've been looking for ways to make smooth inertia scrolling in next.js, but the solutions I've come across are either not performant or have some caveat.

medium article, sandbox, choppy experience,
javascript translate, scroll bar is missing, resizing the window breaks the scrolling as it replaces the scroll event with main.style.transform = translate3d(-${dx}px, -${dy}px, 0px);.

prototyp.digital does a pretty good job--it's subtle, somewhat smooth, and still has a scroll bar. So, it looks like it can be done, but I'm stumped for ideas how.

Rather than doing this with Javascript, set scroll-behavior: smooth; in your CSS.

I'm not looking for smooth scrolling when linking div's. Rather, I want the overall scrolling to be smooth, as shown in some of the linked examples.
